# Display alert before redirecting struts action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a registration page with typical registration fields i will redirect user to login page by struts action if registration got successful i.e. unique username, valid recaptcha etc. But flaw in this approach is that user will not come to know that his registration got successful. How to show him successful registration message before redirecting to another page

Comment: This could be a very informative but imagine if you are in the UNIX environment and you issue a command, the command is executed successfully you know because no message is displayed.

Comment: Show messages on *exceptional* situations, not *normal* ones. That they're no longer on the registration page and can use the site pretty much implies registration was successful.